# How to make a proxy server on a smartphone?

Tags: java, android, proxy

I want to start proxy server on my device. It may by open for all web and working during wifi and cellular connection. I used [this](https://github.com/dawsonice/KissProxy) project like example, and it working not stable. In client app I use this code to connect to proxy in webview:

```
public class ProxySettings {

static final int PROXY_CHANGED = 193;

private static Object getDeclaredField(Object obj, String name) 
    throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, 
    IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Object out = f.get(obj);
        return out;
    }

public static Object getRequestQueue(Context ctx) throws Exception {

    Object ret = null;
    Class networkClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.Network");
    if (networkClass != null) {
        Object networkObj = invokeMethod(networkClass, "getInstance", 
            new Object[] { ctx },
                Context.class);
        if (networkObj != null) {
            ret = getDeclaredField(networkObj, "mRequestQueue");
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

private static Object invokeMethod(Object object, String methodName, 
    Object[] params, Class... types) throws Exception {

        Object out = null;
        Class c = object instanceof Class ? (Class) object : 
            object.getClass();
    if (types != null) {
        Method method = c.getMethod(methodName, types);
        out = method.invoke(object, params);
    } else {
        Method method = c.getMethod(methodName);
        out = method.invoke(object);
    }
    return out;
}

public static void resetProxy(Context ctx) throws Exception {

    Object requestQueueObject = getRequestQueue(ctx);
    if (requestQueueObject != null) {
        setDeclaredField(requestQueueObject, "mProxyHost", null);
    }
}

private static void setDeclaredField(Object obj, String name, Object 
    value) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, 
        IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

           Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
           f.setAccessible(true);
           f.set(obj, value);
}

public static boolean setProxy(Context ctx, String host, int port) {

    boolean ret = false;
    setSystemProperties(host, port);

    try {

        Log.e("MEGATAG", "ProxySettings.setProxy try");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {

            Log.e("MEGATAG", "ProxySettings.setProxy try if");

            Object requestQueueObject = getRequestQueue(ctx);
            if (requestQueueObject != null) {

                HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost(host, port, "http");

                setDeclaredField(requestQueueObject, "mProxyHost", 
                    httpHost);
                ret = true;
            }

        } else {
            ret = setICSProxy(host, port);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return ret;
}

private static boolean setICSProxy(String host, int port) throws 
    ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, 
    IllegalArgumentException, InstantiationException,
    IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        Log.e("MEGATAG", "ProxySettings.setICSProxy");

        Class webViewCoreClass = 
            Class.forName("android.webkit.WebViewCore");
        Class proxyPropertiesClass = 
            Class.forName("android.net.ProxyProperties");
       if (webViewCoreClass != null && proxyPropertiesClass != null){

        Method m = webViewCoreClass
            .getDeclaredMethod("sendStaticMessage", Integer
            .TYPE,Object.class);
        Constructor c = proxyPropertiesClass
            .getConstructor(String.class, Integer.TYPE,String.class);
        m.setAccessible(true);
        c.setAccessible(true);
        Object properties = c.newInstance(host, port, null);
        m.invoke(null, PROXY_CHANGED, properties);
        Log.e("MEGATAG", "setICSProxy true");
        return true;
    }

    Log.e("MEGATAG", "ProxySettings.setICSProxy else -> false");
    return false;

}

private static void setSystemProperties(String host, int port) {

    Log.e("MEGATAG", "ProxySettings.setSystemProperties");

    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port + "");

    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", port + "");

}
}
```

In case, I think, that it work not stable, because the port is blocking, when I connecting to. I was added method, that closed my socket connection to unblock port, And it does not working. May be anyone had this problem and resolved it, and can help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer behind [this](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/java-simple-proxy-socket-server-examples) link. Hope it helps anybody.